# How to export/use socket.io in other files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using a generated NodeJS/ExpressJS/MongoDB/Socket.io backend ([FullstackAcademy/fsg](https://github.com/FullstackAcademy/fsg)) and I want to use the Socket.io part of the app.

Socket.io has it's own file:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io = null;

module.exports = function (server) {
    if (io) return io;
    io = socketio(server);
    io.on('connection', function () {
        // Now have access to socket, wowzers!
    });
    return io;
};
```

And Socket.io is connected to the server in `Main.js`:

```
var chalk = require('chalk');
var startDb = require('./db');
var server = require('http').createServer();

var createApplication = function () {
    var app = require('./app');
    server.on('request', app); // Attach the Express application.
    require('./io')(server);   // Attach socket.io.
};

var startServer = function () {
    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
    server.listen(PORT, function () {
        console.log(chalk.blue('Server started on port', chalk.magenta(PORT)));
    });
};

startDb.then(createApplication).then(startServer).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(chalk.red(err.stack));
    process.kill(1);
});
```

The problem is that I want to access the Socket.io functionality in my routes files but I am not having any luck.  For example, when someone calls the /api/users/testing endpoint, I have this, which currently does not work:

```
router.get('/testing' , function(req, res, next) {
    const io = require('../../../io')(); // from Socket.io file
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('Emitting...');
        socket.emit('new user added', { userData: 'some data here' });
    });
});
```

The `Emitting...` line never gets logged out and the `socket.emit` never fires.  I am thinking that it is because the `io.on('connection',...)` is never being called.

Can anyone tell me how I can use socket.io in my other files with this setup?